# Validating exact length of value

Tags: c#, validation

I am using Microsoft Visual Developer C#. I am trying to validate a textbox so that the Book Code (int) entered is exactly 4 characters long. I used the Range Validator control to do so. For the MaximumValue and MinimumValue properties of the Range Validator I made them both equal 4. However this doesnt seem to work. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: your not showing us your code.

Comment: Yes, you are doing it wrong. If you weren't, it would work. Perhaps you can give us more information?

Comment: You are doing right in concept but you didn't tell what's your problem exactly. Update your question with details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple, you should probably be thinking more about your problem before posting. However, I will empathize with a beginner and give a couple of solutions.

option 1 - convert to a string and check it's length;

```
 string myVar = BookCode.ToString()
 if (myVar.Length < 5)
     // it's good!
 else
    // ERROR
```

option 2 - the largest value less than ten thousand is 9999, a four digit value.

```
 if (BookCode < 10000)
     // it's good
  else
    // it's bad
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just having users enter text into a text box and once they press some type of submit button you want to confirm that the text is 4 characters long then you can check that with `inputControl.Text.Length == 4`

from there you can show a message box and return if it's not equal to 4 or continue if it is.